# Не выполняется сравнение в if

Tags: c, матрицы, сравнение

В чем проблема:

в строке `if (b == matr_words[i][0])` - допустим я введу слово `first` как `word` и `first time games did occur cause killed victim`.

По идее должен выдать `well done`, но он не выдает почему?

Можете сказать что я делаю не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h >
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define N 100000
unsigned char matr_words[N][3][81];
char word[N], words[N], ABC_words[N];
char words_v2[N];

int find(char* word, char* words)
{
    char* istr;
    istr = strstr(words, word);
    int t = istr - words;
    if (istr == NULL) return -1;
    else return t;
}

int main() {
    int wd = 0, ws = 0, kol_enter = 0, kol_strok = 0;
    scanf("%[^' ']s", word); while (getchar() != ' ');
    scanf("%[^' ']s", words); while (getchar() != ' ');
    wd = strlen(words);
    ws = strlen(word);


    int slova = 0, alllenn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < wd; i++) {                   //здесь считается сколько слов||строк в коде
        if (words[i] == '\n') kol_enter++;
        kol_strok = kol_enter + 1;
        if (words[i] != '\n') slova++;
    }
    alllenn = slova + kol_enter - 1;                 //new_len_words-длина без вычеркнутового слова

    int sym_word = 0;                                //alllenn - общее число бкув + ентеров
    for (int i = 0; i < ws; i++) {
        if (word[i] != '\n') sym_word++;
    }
    //сортировка по алфавиту 
    int y = find(word, words);                       // y - начало делитного слова
    int  new_len_words = 0;
    int wdw = sym_word + 1;                          //WDW(weight delite word) - 
    if (y != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            words_v2[i] = words[i];
        }
        for (int i = y; i < (alllenn - wdw + 1); i++) words_v2[i] = words[i + wdw];
    }
    new_len_words = alllenn - wdw;
    for (int i = 0; i < new_len_words + 1; i++) {
        printf("%c", words_v2[i]);
    }

    unsigned char matr_word[1][80];
    char b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sym_word; i++) { //последняя буква word
        b = word[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= sym_word; i++) { //заносим в матрицу последнее букву ключегового слова
        matr_word[0][0] = b;
        matr_word[0][i + 1] = word[i];
    }
    printf("\n");

    int n = 0;
    char* w = strtok(words_v2, "\n");
    while (w != NULL) //пока есть лексемы
    {
        matr_words[n][0][0] = w[0];
        matr_words[n][0][1] = 0;//конец строки
        matr_words[n][1][0] = w[strlen(w) - 1];
        matr_words[n][1][1] = 0; //конец строки
        strcpy(matr_words[n][2], w);
        n++;

        w = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
    //for (int i = 0; i < kol_enter - 1; i++) {
        //printf(" %s %s %s\n", matr_words[i][0], matr_words[i][1], matr_words[i][2]);
    //}


    for (int i = 0; i < kol_enter - 1; i++) {
        if (b != matr_words[i][0]) { printf("try another words :(\n"); break; }
        if (b == matr_words[i][0]) {printf("well done"); break;
        }
    }
    


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: if (b != matr_words[i][0]) { printf("try another words :(\n"); break; } здесь закрывается скобка, а здесь if (b == matr_words[i][0]) {printf("well done"); break; ее нет. Попробуйте скобку перенести вконец следующей строчки

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

Что значит *не работает* ? На самом деле, ваш код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kol_enter - 1; i++) {
  if (b != matr_words[i][0]) { printf("try another words :(\n"); break; }
  if (b == matr_words[i][0]) {printf("well done"); break; }
}
```

Полностью эквивалентен такому:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kol_enter - 1; i++) {

  if (b != matr_words[i][0]) 
     printf("try another words :(\n");
  else
     printf("well done");

  break;
}
```

Получается, что оператор *break;* срабатывает **всегда** при первой же итерации цикла. Зачем тогда цикл?!

Сдаётся мне, что один из операторов *break;* - лишний.

Comment: спасибо за улучшение кода, но он все равно не сравнивает правильно

Comment: @nineirl в Си сравнение символьных массивов через == или != сравнивает значения указателей, а не текста в этих массивах. Используйте функцию strcmp.

Comment: @nineirl - "сравнение символьных массивов" - Но здесь *(b != matr_words[i][0])* сравниваются именно символы, а не строки.

Comment: @nineirl - "он все равно не сравнивает правильно" - Исправьте исходный текст в вопросе, что бы можно было понять, что имеется сейчас и покажите, что именно сортируется неправильно.